# What's wrong with this Pascal syntax?

Tags: pascal

I can't understand what's going on here. Can you give me a hand? This is the problematic code:

```
While not EOF(Archi) do begin
  index:= index + 1;
  Read(Archi, Alumno[index]);
  Promes[index] := (Alumno[index].nota1 + Alumno[index].nota2) / 2;
  if Promes[index] >= 6 then begin
     alguPromo := true;
     PromosIndex := PromosIndex + 1;
     Promos[PromosIndex]:= Alumno[index];
  end;
  else begin
       if Promes[index] > 4 then cantiRecu:= cantiRecu + 1;
       else begin
            LibresIndex += 1;
            Libres[LibresIndex] := Alumno[index];
            end;
  end;
end;
```

The compiler marks error in the line 10 of this code (else begin). The error is:
    Fatal: Syntax error, ; expected but ELSE found.

If someone wants to tray compile here is the entire code: http://pastebin.com/dRg1Lguu

Comment: Are you sure that pascal support += operator?

Comment: What is the problem with the code?

Comment: There should **not** be a semicolon after the `end` before the `else`. Ditto for the line `cantiRecu:= cantiRecu + 1` - this should not have a semicolon either.

Comment: Thanks man! Was the semicolon! I had a suspect that was that, but i couldn't fix it. Done. Thanks man.

Comment: @user1491651: OK - I've fleshed this out into a complete answer now - please up-vote and accept it if it has been useful to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that in Pascal the semicolon is a *separator*, not a *terminator*. Sometimes this doesn't matter, but in some cases it does, particularly before an `else`. Your code should be:

```
while not EOF(Archi) do
  begin
    index:= index + 1;
    Read(Archi, Alumno[index]);
    Promes[index] := (Alumno[index].nota1 + Alumno[index].nota2) / 2;
    if Promes[index] >= 6 then
      begin
        alguPromo := true;
        PromosIndex := PromosIndex + 1;
        Promos[PromosIndex] := Alumno[index]
      end
    else
      begin
        if Promes[index] > 4 then
          cantiRecu:= cantiRecu + 1
        else
          begin
            LibresIndex := LibresIndex + 1;
            Libres[LibresIndex] := Alumno[index]
          end
      end
  end
```

Note that I have re-formatted the code into a more conventional style which helps to make the program logic more easily understood and which also makes it more obvious where the semicolons are needed and where they are not.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem in += operator

Comment: Free Pascal allows C style increments with a special parameter. It is meant for conversion purposes though, and is not for new code directly written in Pascal.